# I need help with a formula for a conditional column in a form

Tags: 2013, column

If "Other" is checked in column 1 then column 2 (Please specify)is to be displayed. What is a valid formula for this?

Comment: Please update your tags to include which version of SP you're using

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to achieve is to display a field (enter a  other value) based on the selection of another field (i.e choosing other from choice) . Out of the Box , hiding/showing a field is not possible on the form. By Default , Checkbox provide options to allow "Fill in options" which will allow you to add your own value.

[image]

or

Customizing the list form is one other option using designer . Let me know which path you are after .

Comment: We are not allowed to utilize anything that is not out of the box at this time. So I will default to option 1. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Cool @AundreaMauldin ! let me know if you need any other question on that.